# How offset works

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to know that, How offset works in WPF in GradientStop

```
 <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
 </Grid.Background>
```

Answer (score 2):

StartPoint has default value 0,0 and EndPoint has default value 1,1.  As you have not specified StartPoint and EndPoint, these values are implicitly used. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush(v=vs.110).aspx

Finally, it is important to note that brushes have a BrushMappingMode property which defaults to RelativeToBoundingBox.  As you have not specified that, RelativeToBoundingBox is used and offset determines the position of the color between your endpoints.  Another option is Absolute, which is where the magnitude of EndPoint-StartPoint starts mattering.

When you specify a gradientstop at offset 0.3 using BrushMappingMode RelativeToBoundingBox, you're specifying the color of the linear gradient 30% between StartPoint and EndPoint.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's the point at which the gradient switches completely over to the next color.  So something like:

```
<Rectangle Width="200" Height="100">
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
      <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.0" />
      <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.25" />
      <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75" />
      <GradientStop Color="LimeGreen" Offset="1.0" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

from 0 to 25% of the rectangle will flow from yellow to red.  25% to 75% of the rectangle will flow from red to blue.  From 75% - 100% the rectangle will be blue to lime green.

So in your example, the color will go from black to red, with the colors only being completely black at the start and completely red at the end.